# Creating a HashMap as an index for title keywords to improve search efficiency

Tags: java, search, arraylist, hashmap

I have a custom class `Disks` which stores various information of CDs such as their Title, Length, Artist etc.  These `Disks` objects are stored in an `ArrayList` which can only have elements of `Disks` added.  I am using a method to search for these objects based on  matching their title.  It takes a user input and then goes through each element of the list and compares the user keyword and the Title of the CD.  If it is a complete match, its information is then returned to the user.

I want to change this search mechanization slightly by incorporating a HashMap.  I am looking to tokenize each `Disks` Title and then create a mapping entry for the keyword.

Here is an example: The word "Cars" appears in the titles of the `ArrayList` elements at position 0,5,7.  I want to be able to create a mapping entry for "Cars" which will be a list [0,5,7].  If another element is added to the `ArrayList` at position 10 with "Cars" in the title, how would I amend the old mapping entry so the new list would be [0,5,7,10]?

In the end I want the user to search for title keywords “Loud Cars”.  I will first find "loud" in the index to get a list of [0,7,5] (for example), and then find "cars" to get a list of [0,5,7,10].  Then, I will find where these lists intersect and return the `ArrayList` elements that correspond to these locations.

My current HashMap declartion looks like this: `public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();` however even when the Key is different, the values stored in the ArrayList are the same because there is only one of them.

My `Disks ArrayList` is: `public ArrayList<Disks> items;` Would there be a way to incorporate this ArrayList into the Value of the HashMap?

Comment: `however even when the Key is different, the values stored in the ArrayList are the same because there is only one of them.` Could you be more specific? Why there's only a instance of the indexes ArrayList? Also, can you show us how you add the couples to the map?

Comment: Because as the number of possible Keys grows wouldn't I need a new indexes ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new value to the index entry for "Cars"

```
map.get("Cars").add(10);
```

Safe way to do this (key = "Cars", index = 10):

```
ArrayList<Integer> entry = map.get(key);
if (entry == null) {
  entry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  map.put(key, entry);
}
entry.add(index);
```

Instead of using

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>
```

I'd recommend

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>
```

Which is automatically avoids duplicates.

When you search for multiple words, use `retainAll` to build the intersection of multiple sets (but copy the first set because retainAll is destructive):

```
Set<Integer> resultSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
resultSet.addAll(map.get("Cars"));
resultSet.retainAll(map.get("Loud"));
```

Comment: So this would take the Key Cars, and then add 10 to the associated arraylist?

Comment: Yes, it takes the map value for the key "Cars", which is an arraylist, and appends 10 to the arraylist.

Comment: So if I had the key "Sound" and preformed the same operation with location 9, it would automatically append 9 to the list associated with "Sound"  and leave the list for "Cars" alone?

Comment: Yes, if you refer to the "safe way" above.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new ArrayList of Integer for every string mapping to a value. The first time an entry is used, you create a new list (You must check that the string maps to null), and add the value of the index that the new Disk entry will be stored at in your ArrayList of Disls to you ArrayList of Integers. Any time the string maps to a non-empty list, then you just add the index (where it is in the Disk ArrayList) to the ArrayList of Integer.

Comment: I like this answer but how would I be able to ddynamically create these integer arrayLists?

Comment: Every time you add a disk to the list, you tokenize the title. For each token you see if there is already an Arraylist in the Hashmap, if there is not (it's null) you would say map.put(disk.title(),new ArrayList<Integer>());

Comment: I think I've found my disconnect now.  I didn't realize that the HashMap could keep track of new arrayLists as I needed to create them for the Keys.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think the best way for you to scale your solution is by using bloom filters or something sophisticated like this. This would require you to create complex hash codes, manage false positives, among other things.

Having that said, based on your design, I think what you can simply have a hash map pointing to the Disks objects that are also stored on the array list.

```
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Disks>> map
```

For the keyword "cars", you have a list of Disks objects. For the keyword "loud" you have another list of Disks objects. Just take both lists and find the intersection, using the  `retainAll()` method.

Make sure to override hashCode() and equals() in Disks so all collections will work fine.

Comment: This makes sense but I would have too many arrayLists of the Disk class to manage.

Comment: Yes, that is the drawback. That is why I suggested using bloom filters. Basically, you need to calculate a hash for each Disks object. Such hash represents the presence or absence of certain words (assuming you have a finite and small number of keywords makes it easier to understand such solution). Say the words are simply "loud", "car", and "blue". Then each Disks object will have a hash code whose value could range from 000 to 111.

If your number of keywords is larger, than obviously you cannot keep adding bits in the hash code. Then you need to cope with false positives.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I think I am going to go with the suggestion made by Stefan which seems simple and easier to manage for my scale.

Comment: To understand false positives, consider another example. The first bit (least significant) means that there is the letter "a" somewhere in the title. Then "cars" will have a 1 on the first bit, but so will "cats". Both words are quite similar, so the hash codes will maybe fool you into finding a false positive.

I believe your solution should try to organize this kind of complexity. If this is a professional project, I recommend using a framework that already implements this, such as Apache Lucene.